# Ways Of Finding Primes and If they are efficient

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am currently in middle school and love number theory. I try and do a proof every day and today I was working on a relatively simple one involving primes. I proved that every prime above 5 can be represented as the sqrt(24n+1). p where p is prime has a p-1 and a p+1 such that for either p-1 or p+1 they are a multiple of 3 as p cannot be a multiple of 3. Therefore, p-1(p+1)=6x. p-1(p+1)=p^2-1 so we just proved that p2-p=6x. Also, either p-1 or p+1 must be a multiple of 4 and the other a multiple of 2 so we get p-1(p+1)=8y where p^2-1=8y. The least common multiple of both 6 and  is 24 proving that for all p^2-1 where p>5 that p^2-1=24x. Play with it, its kind of cool. But this got me thinking of other numbers that are equivalent to sqrt(24n+1) but not prime. I then proved that on average for the nth prime where n is above about 15 or 20, the percentage of when it is a whole number being prime is just barely above .333333 repeating. I proved this by showing that all mine does is take out all odds that are multiples of 3 and then took all odds that are products of numbers below n. Is .33333 repeating percent efficient for finding primes. I don't know how often the Mersenne prime finder works but I guess it gets less as the primes as the the exponent prime get larger while as my number get larger it will just converge to about .3333333. Thank you. My question is really about efficiency but if there is an error in either of my proofs please do let me know.
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean "it is a whole number"? What is "it"?

Comment: it being sqrt(24n+1). Sorry about that

Comment: I do not know what you are saying about $0.33\dots$.  After a while, "most" numbers are not prime.

Comment: Clarification is key. If you are not sure whether or not to explain too much or too little, go for too much. Try avoiding words like "it" or generally vague terms. It is much better to over explain even if it takes a lot longer.

Comment: A lot of what you wrote can be explained by the fact that all primes except for $2$ and $3$ are of the form $6n\pm1$.

Comment: It is very hard to find very large primes because the probability that a number $n$ is prime is roughly $\frac{1}{ln(n)}$. To find a prime number with a million digits, you have to check about $2.3*10^6$ numbers in the average before finding a prime. Of course, some numbers are quickly detected to be composite (even numbers, numbers divisible by $3$,...), but even after sieving, a large number of candidates are left. There are quick methods to check, if a number is prime, but for a number with a million digits, it will take quite a while.

Comment: Numbers with size $1,000-10,000$ digits can be found relatively quickly, unless it should be a PROVEN prime. If you are confident with a number that is composite with probability smaller than, lets say $10^{-18}$, you can easily find such a number using the RABIN-MILLER-TEST.